# PHP Magic Method __sleep and __wakeup and PDO connection

Tags: php, oop, pdo, connection, database-connection

Can someone explain how this example from php manual works?
Its found here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

1. What is the benefit of using magic method for establishing PDO
   connection as per this example from PHP manual. I don't get it, why would i need to use `serialize()` and `__sleep()` and `__wakeup()` to establish database connection?
2. After connection is established handle for it
   will be in `$link` variable and how do i use it by extending this
   class with a child class?
3. How do i pass $link to other classes that will not inherit `Connection` class, only way is to make it `static`?
4. How do i go about closing connection to PDO should i close it on script execution has ended or when object Connection is destroyed?

x

```
class Connection {
    protected $link;
    private   $dsn, $username, $password;

    public function __construct($dsn, $username, $password) {
        $this->dsn      = $dsn;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->connect();
    }

    private function connect() {
        $this->link = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->password);
    }

    public function __sleep() {
        return array('dsn', 'username', 'password');
    }

    public function __wakeup() {
        $this->connect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PDO connections don't persist between different script executions, so it doesn't make sense to try to include them when serializing an object that contains a database connection. So when you serialize and unserialize this class, you need some way of re-establishing an equivalent connection.

An example of how this might be used is if you try to save the `Connection` object in a session variable. The PHP session facility uses `serialize()` to convert data to a format that can be saved in a file or stored in a database.

The assumption in this example is that the `Connection` class is how you do all your database access. They didn't show the whole class definition, just enough to demonstrate the use of these magic methods. In a real application, you might have a `getLink()` method that returns `$this->link`, or you would add other methods that perform queries using `$this->link`. You could also add a `close()` method that does `$this->link = null;`.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's unconventional, but the `__sleep` will store your passed credentials in the serialized object and `__wakeup` re-establishes it when you de-serialize it. Just be aware that if you choose this method over, say, constants stored in your PHP script somewhere, anywhere you store the serialized data will contain your DB credentials
2. `link` does indeed store the `PDO` object
3. Just use a getter method to get the `PDO` object

   ```
   public function getConnection() {
        return $this->link;
   }
   ```
4. In most cases you don't need to close your connection. All connections that are not explicitly persistent will be closed when the script shuts down